# Nativescript Socket connection timeouted

Tags: android, nativescript

Recently I have started facing a strange issue with Nativescript. When I try to run the android application using **tns run android** I get following error message

**Unable to apply changes on device: HQ64MZ576132. Error is: Socket connection timeouted..**

I dont know how to identify the actual issue. To fix this issue, I need to copy app folder from another working nativescript application and then replace all the file from repository and eventually I am back to normal running application. 
Following is what I am trying to figure out:

1. How to identify what is causing **Socket connection timeouted**?
2. Why replacing the whole app solves the issue even when the files are exactly 
   same which doesnt make sense to me?

Following is my package.json

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.travel",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"app/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-admob": "^1.4.2",
    "nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.1",
    "nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-grid-view": "^3.4.0",
    "nativescript-purchase": "^2.0.5",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.5.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "^3.8.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.3",
    "babel-traverse": "6.4.5",
    "babel-types": "6.4.5",
    "babylon": "6.4.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.3.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "1.3.5",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "0.5.1",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.16.2",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.8.1",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~2.2.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^4.2.0",
    "tslint": "5.8.0",
    "typescript": "2.8.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.1.6",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
    "webpack-sources": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: May I know what you have in your `package.json`?

Comment: Updated package.json in the question. I dont need to replace package.json file to fix this issue thats why I thought package.json should be fine.

Comment: Is your package name `com.travel` same in your app.gradle & android manifest files?

Comment: I have applicationId = "com.travel" in app.gradle file but dont have the package name in Android manifest file. It still used to run ok.

Comment: i am having the same problem, did you resolve it @Rakesh

Comment: I couldnt figure out the exact way to fix this issue. I deleted node_modules, hooks, platforms folders. Remove and Add platforms. If none of this work then to copy app folder from another working nativescript application and then replace all the file from repository and eventually I am back to normal running application. I couldn't find the pattern and exact reason why it is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a nasty issue which ate most of my days. It was nativescript-admob plugin which was causing application to break. Version 17.0.0 of Google Mobile Ads SDK requires  tag in AndroidManifest.xml. You can find more info here https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml. There is open issue https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-admob/issues/45 which has a temp.
You will have to add following line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <!-- this line needs to be added (replace the value!) -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713" />

    <activity></activity>
</application>
```