# Error is: Socket connection timed out.. Android Application

Tags: android, angular, firebase, nativescript, startup

I am on Windows 10 and I want to run my app on a USB-C connected Android device.

My first step is always to remove node_modules, hooks and platforms folders, aswell as package.lock.json file. After that I run tns build android. Once the build is completed I either run tns run android or start the application via nativescript sidekick show nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare, and in  ends like this now:

Project successfully built. Installing on device 5B24000362... Successfully installed on device with identifier '5B24000362'. Unable to apply changes on device: 5B24000362. Error is: Socket connection timed out..

Since I had this error already 2 days ago and could not continue working on the App, I updated nativescript and nativescript-plugin-firebase.

My package.json

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "profiling": "timeline",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.project",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~6.0.0",
    "nativescript": "^5.1.1",
    "nativescript-accordion": "^5.0.4",
    "nativescript-angular": "~6.0.0",
    "nativescript-barcodescanner": "^2.7.8",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^1.1.5",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^7.7.0",
    "nativescript-push-notifications": "^1.1.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.6",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^3.5.8",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^4.1.1",
    "nativescript-urlhandler": "^1.2.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.1.0",
    "tns-android": "^4.2.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^4.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~6.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~6.1.0",
    "babel-traverse": "6.4.5",
    "babel-types": "6.4.5",
    "babylon": "6.4.5",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: By any chance did you change your package id for Android?

Comment: If you are using admob from nativescript-plugin-firebase then update your Androidmanifest.xml as suggested in https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ADMOB.md

Comment: @Manoj No, I update only tns-android and nativescript and nativescript-plugin-firebase

Comment: @Rakesh I change It but nothing happens

Comment: I had similar issue which you can find here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53134843/nativescript-socket-connection-timeouted

Comment: @Manoj Changing the applicationId in app.gradle is _exactly_ what I had done. Put it back to its default and now everything works as expected 